# Consulta Between MySQL não retornar correto!

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma consulta simples num campo `Datetime`, devo fazer a consulta informando duas datas, é claro recuperando os valores entre elas.

```
select 
  financ_conta_id,
  financ_conta_cadastro
from
  financ_conta 
where
  financ_conta_cadastro between CURRENT_DATE()-3 and CURRENT_DATE()
```

Se mantenho assim, os dados cadastros hoje não são exibidos, mostram apenas os valores de ontem menos 3 dias, ou seja, minhas contas cadastradas em 21/07 não são exibidas, sendo que hoje é 21/07.

O resultado está retornando como se tivesse feito isso:

```
 financ_conta_cadastro between CURRENT_DATE()-3 and '2016-07-22'
```

O que há de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderá utitlizar o INTERVAL para tirar a diferença de uma data por dias, mês, ano;

```
SELECT financ_conta_id, financ_conta_cadastro FROM financ_conta 
WHERE financ_conta_cadastro BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o [DATE() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) para converter seu DateTime para um Date, assim você não contará as horas do dia.

```
select 
  financ_conta_id,
  financ_conta_cadastro
from
  financ_conta 
where
  DATE(financ_conta_cadastro) between DATE(CURRENT_DATE()-3) and DATE(CURRENT_DATE())
```